# How to properly clear/dispose Disposable which periodically performs Completable?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a disposable which in some time interval performs request to the API

```
   val disposable =
    Flowable.interval(0, UPDATE_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map {
          someRepository.sync(id)
              .doOnSubscribe { disposables?.add(it) }
              .subscribe()
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError { Timber.e(it, "Unable to sync") }
        .subscribe()
disposables?.add(disposable)
```

I am trying to clear it inside the onBackPressed method:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed()
  disposables?.dispose()
}
```

However it is not cleared and I see in the Android Studio Profiler that it is still performing this Flowable after I've clicked the back button.

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

When i change map operator to flatMap as akarnokd suggested:

```
Error:(160, 11) Type inference failed: fun <R : Any!> flatMap(p0: 
((Long) -> Publisher<out R!>!)!, p1: Int): Flowable<R!>!
cannot be applied to
((Long) -> Completable,Int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are subscribing in a handler instead of using `flatMap`/`concatMap`:

```
val disposable =
Flowable.interval(0, UPDATE_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .flatMapCompletable ({ someRepository.sync(id) }, 1)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ }, { Timber.e(it, "Unable to sync") })

disposables.add(disposable)

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    disposables.clear()
}
```

2) you can specify the thread of `interval`. 3) `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` has no effect as `interval` emits on its own thread. 4) `doOnError` is not error handling but only error peeking. An error would still crash your flow/app. 5) `disposables.clear()` is usually a better call to cleanup running flows so that you can reuse the same `disposables` next time.

> I see in the Android Studio Profiler that it is still performing

Even though awkward, your original setup should have stopped on `dispose()`. My best guess is that `disposables?.add` doesn't execute because `disposables` is or becomes null at some point.

Comment: I was trying the flatMap first, but i was getting type inrefence error on flatMap(on your code also):

Comment: Use `flatMapCompletable`.

Comment: Thanks, after your suggestion it works - however I was forced by IDE to remove the second parameter from the flatMapCompletable method

Comment: I don't know Kotlin so I don't know how to have a Java functional interface lambda and a parameter together. That parameter was supposed to prevent running your `sync` call overlappingly if one takes longer than the time interval.